# exec() doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, linux, apache, exec

I'm running a script using `exec` from a `php` file. In the scipt there is a creation of a folder and a file inside it. The folder is created well but it remains empty after the script is finished.
I have looked at the return value from the `exec` call and everything seems about right, so I'm not sure if it's `permissions` problem or not(wouldn't I get `permission denied` if that was the case?).
Anyway if it is permission problem' please tell me how to give the right permissions to the `www-data` user.

[Edit]:
I have played with the script a little and I saw that it can create files in that folder. The problem is, that the script create the file I need like this: `sqlite3 myFile.db < mySql.sql`, so the problem is probably there. Any ideas?

Comment: What are the file permissions and owner (as given with `ls -ls`) on that script? If it is a shell script you might add logging messages in it with `logger`

Comment: It it can make the folder, it can make the file. Show the code :)

Comment: `exec` would be closed in php.ini, please check log files.

Comment: Make your script output the results of `is_writable('your dir')` to easily check if the script is actually able to write.

Comment: It would help btw if you posted the code you are using to write your file..

Comment: @MihaiIorga you're right. I have played with the script a little and I saw that it can create files in that folder. The problem is, that the script create the file I need like this:
`sqlite3 myFile.db < mySql.sql`, so the problem is probably there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After creating the folder please give permission to it by using below code

chmod("complete-folder-path", 0777);

After that create file in it. It will work.

Comment: That would only work if the www-data user actually has the permissions to change folder permissions, which it probably doesn't since it would then probably be able to write in it aswell..